# calling a php function in my code with clicking an image

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a php function that I like to run in my code when a particular image is clicked. Currently I'm using an onclick function in javascript but it seems like the function is run everytime I refresh the page as opposed to just when I click the image. Can you guys please help me understand this? Should I be running a AJAX script?

Comment: Can you explain more or add some code?

Is the image a link to somewhere or just a clickable image? If so Ajax is your answer. 

You can also use a <input type="image" /> but again I can't understand your problem enouth to say.

Comment: This is an image which is a link to somewhere. I would like to execute a php function in the code when that linked image is clicked.

Comment: And the page refresh, or a part of the page refresh as a consequence of this image click event?

Answer (score 3):

This is an "order of execution" problem: All PHP code is executed before any HTML is presented to the user. If you want PHP to execute based on a user action, you need to initiate a new request to the server (via AJAX or a standard link).

Comment: thanks for the reply. Do you know where I can find an example of how to do this please?

Comment: @mark: The jQuery framework provides easy AJAX functionality: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://api.jquery.com/load/ . There are many available examples (Gmail, Facebook, etc) depending on what you wish to achieve.

Comment: For a pretty good explanation on AJAX you could go to w3schools as well. It will provide a pretty easy to understand step by step explanation of the process as a whole.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp

Comment: @mark: If one of the answers on this page helped you figure it out, please click the checkmark to accept it. If you found a different explanation that helped you, please post it as an answer and accept that. This will help future readers of your question to find the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just link the image to the PHP file that contains your function call?

If you want it without having to refresh the page, then you can make an asynchronous call via AJAX to the said PHP file, and perform the necessary functions.