# how to call a php script after clicking on an image html?

Tags: php, html, onclick

I'm developping a web aplication with html, i want to call a php script when clicking on an image so i used this code

```
 <img src="photo/suppc.png" width="295" height="36" onclick="<?php
 include("D:/EasyPHP-5.3.3.1/www/supcont.php"); 
 ?>" target="fenetreA"   />
```

but this code php is executed when showing the image (before clicking on it)

Comment: This is not how it works. You need to link the image to a new URL (the PHP script): `<a href="supcont.php"><img src="..."></a>"` however, you will need to link to a http location, not a server path

Comment: Refer the following link,it may help for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509153/calling-a-php-function-in-my-code-with-clicking-an-image

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="document.location.href='/supcont.php';return false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed your Image into a hyperlink. Try something like this:

```
<a href="supcont.php" target="fenetreA"><img src="photo/suppc.png" width="295" height="36"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side language. You can't include PHP scripts into HTML

You can do something like this

```
 <img src="photo/suppc.png" width="295" height="36" onclick="supcont.php" target="fenetreA" />
```

I think that's the only solution here.

Good luck!

Comment: thx but this doesn't work :( the problem is that i have a function in the php script that i want to call

Comment: You need to put a piece of JavaScript in the onclick attribute, not a filename.

Comment: @emma Sorry, you can't call that function via html or javascript. You can only load a php page that call that function.

Comment: i can load php page but not when i click th image, it is loaded automatically when launch the html page

Comment: @emna yes, you load it because when your script run first-time see in your code `<?php
 include("D:/EasyPHP-5.3.3.1/www/supcont.php"); 
 ?>`. You can pun this code everywhere you want in your code, will have the same result. I tell you, what you want it's not posible with PHP!

Comment: is there any solution to call it juste when i press the image

Comment: @emna why you don't use JavaScript? what kind of code you have in supcont.php ?

Comment: include("xmpphp/XMPPHP/xmpp.php");
$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('192.168.143.62', 5222, 'emna', '96110839', 'xmpphp', 'emna-pc', $printlog=False, $loglevel = XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);
$conn->connect();
$conn->processUntil('session_start');
$conn->presence(); 
$conn->message('amouna@emna-pc', 'suppsms');
$conn->disconnect();

Comment: Try to send a GET request to supcont.php with JavaScript when you click on image :)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function doSomething() {
     $.get("D:/EasyPHP-5.3.3.1/www/supcont.php");
      }
      </script>
i tried this code but it does not recognize the get

Comment: `jQuery.get("supcont.php", function() {
    alert("success");
  });` enter URL not PATH

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side thing so that isn't going to work because it is always transformed to the corresponding output *prior* to being pushed down the wire. If you want client-side UI scripting then you'll need to use Javascript or something.

Ideally you would just wrap the image in a link and make that link point to the proper destination, then the browser handles the clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call directly php on clicking image. This can be done in two steps:

1. click an image and go to JavaScript
2. Trigger AJAX(eg. jquery AJAX) in js and reach PHP

```js
function imageJs() {
  var data = 'your data to pass into PHP';
  $ajax({
    url: 'a.php',
    data: data,
    type: POST,
  });

  success: function (res) {
    alert ('successfully in PHP');
  }
  error: function (err) {
    alert('error reaching PHP');
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<img src='a.png' onclick=imageJs()>
</html>
```